# Why cant I configure or remove this module?

Tags: 8, google-analytics

I was trying to figure out [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) and installing it broke my site so I uninstalled it.  Now I have reinstalled it, There is no link to configure it and the configuration page isn't even accessible from the URL.

So I tried to uninstall the module again and when I try to uninstall it goes to white screen and when I refresh I get back to the modules list and the module is still there.  I cannot configure or uninstall or get the module to work. It seems to be stuck there.

I have even tried to WinSCP into the server and straight up delete the module.  This removes the file from the list but when I reinstall the module I am back to square 1 where I cannot do anything with it.

I checked the error log and when I try to uninstall I get the following error PHP Fatal error: "Call to undefined function google_analytics_clear_js_cache()"

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: No, there isn't. google_analytics does not work right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I checked the error log and when I try to uninstall I get the following error PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function google_analytics_clear_js_cache()

This means that there is a bug in this module (and off-topic here).

But this is a general problem, and this anser provides is a general solution to this problem, that can also be used with other modules.

Whenever you get a WSOD upon *uninstall* and the log tell you it is because a "Call to an undefined function" - locate that call in the module's source code, and just *delete* the statement with the call.  Then try to uninstall again.

After doing this, make sure you *report* the problem to the module's issue queue on Drupal.org to make the maintainer fix it (and alert others about it).

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee it will help, but I think it's worth trying: increase your php memory limit and try again.

Since you're experiencing problems because of "adding" modules, it could well be that you've reached a memory limit that causes these kinds of related problems ...

Comment: Well I checked the error log and when I try to uninstall I get the following error


PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function google_analytics_clear_js_cache()

Answer (score -1):

Just uninstall the module and clear the cache.May be it will work.

Comment: Downvoted. This is really bad advice.  Removing a folder from the modules directory *without* making *sure* that the module has been properly uninstalled may leave all sorts of cruft in the database that may create problems later.

Comment: Yeah you may be right.But still i think this is related to cache.